# how to refactor adding custom icons in angular-material

Tags: angular, angular-material

To add custom icons and then use them in the mat-icon tag, do this, which already works for me:

```
private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer){
      this.sessionService.currentLanguage = 'es';
      this.matIconRegistry
        .addSvgIcon("downloadIcon", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../../assets/images/icons/download-arrow.svg"))
        .addSvgIcon("filterIcon", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../../assets/images/icons/filter-icon.svg"))
        .addSvgIcon("investmentIcon", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../../assets/images/icons/investment-icon.svg"))
        .addSvgIcon("pensionFundsIcon", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../../assets/images/icons/pension-funds-icon.svg"))
        .addSvgIcon("realEstatesIcon", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../../assets/images/icons/real-estates-icon.svg"))
        .addSvgIcon("logoutIcon", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../../assets/images/icons/sign-off-icon.svg"))
        .addSvgIcon("downArrowIcon", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../../assets/images/icons/down-arrow-icon.svg"))
        .addSvgIcon("upArrowIcon", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../../assets/images/icons/up-arrow-icon.svg"))
        .addSvgIcon("90RigthArrozIcon", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../../assets/images/icons/90-right-arrow-icon.svg"))
        .addSvgIcon("documents", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../../assets/images/icons/documents.svg"))
        .addSvgIcon("previewIcon", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../../assets/images/icons/preview-icon.svg"));
    }
```

But I want it to be something more generic, maybe not to repeat so much code, how could I do it? It occurs to me to make a for, that goes through and has a name of the icon and uses it in the route and in the name, but is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this, I add the solution

```
  icons = [
    { name: 'downloadIcon', route: 'download-arrow' },
    { name: 'filterIcon', route: 'filter-icon' },
    { name: 'investmentIcon', route: 'investment-icon' },
    { name: 'pensionFundsIcon', route: 'pension-funds-icon' },
    { name: 'realEstatesIcon', route: 'real-estates-icon' },
    { name: 'logoutIcon', route: 'sign-off-icon' },
    { name: 'downArrowIcon', route: 'down-arrow-icon' },
    { name: 'upArrowIcon', route: 'up-arrow-icon' },
    { name: '90RigthArrozIcon', route: '90-right-arrow-icon' },
    { name: 'documents', route: 'documents' },
    { name: 'previewIcon', route: 'preview-icon' },
  ];


 and later 
  loadIcons(): void {
    this.icons.forEach(icon => {
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(icon.name, this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`../../assets/images/icons/${icon.route}.svg`));
    });
  }

Then call it in the constructor

private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer){
      this.sessionService.currentLanguage = 'es';
      this.loadIcons();
    }
```